# javafx clickable image Map

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

how can i implement clickable image map in javafx.when i click on the map i want to print that particular state name. The similar example found [here](http://irishpubs.nl/index.php?lang=0&page=1&prov=4)

can it is possible in javafx?if yes.then...How?
i used

```
imageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

            mytext.setText(p.toString());
                System.out.println(p.toString());



            }
        });
```

on image but it not full my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I guess [PuzzlePieces](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle/src/4f1f197a845d/Ensemble2/src/main/java/ensemble/samples/graphics/PuzzlePieces.java) demo is a very best and helpful example for what you want to do. Have a look on the provided link.

https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle/src/4f1f197a845d/Ensemble2/src/main/java/ensemble/samples/graphics/PuzzlePieces.java

Comment: What do I do if the image's pieces aren't regular?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
imageImport.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.print(mouseEvent.getX());
        System.out.print(mouseEvent.getY());

    }
});
```

or you want more than the x and y ?

Comment: no... not this. i have image of map(Like USA) when i click image map it shoul show me state name.

Comment: mouseEvent.getX() and mouseEvent.getY() will changed i any one resize the image. so i need another way ..?